# Build hyperlink between Author name and footer

Tags: xetex, hyperref, hyperlink, hypertarget

In the following code, I try to build a hyperlink between the `Author name` and `left hand footer`. That is to say, when I click the text `Author name`(made by `\author`), the page view will jump to `left hand footer`. Yet The code has now two problems:

(1) Hyperlink is not built.

(2) The content of `\lfoot` is pushed down.

How to solve these problems?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,hyperref}%
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=red,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=green,
  pagebackref,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  bookmarksopen,
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lfoot{\phantomsection\label{lfoot}editor: xx}
\cfoot{center footer}
\rfoot{rhight footer}
\title{title}
\author{\hyperref[lfoot]{\XeTeXLinkBox{Author Name}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
Some text. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `hypertarget` and `hyperlink`. You should also ensure that the target is only on one page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,hyperref}%
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=red,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=green,
  pagebackref,
  bookmarksnumbered,
  bookmarksopen,
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lfoot{\ifnum\value{page}=1 \hypertarget{lfoot}editor: xx\fi}

\author{\hyperlink{lfoot}{\XeTeXLinkBox{Author Name}}}

\title{title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}
Some text.
\newpage 
second page
\end{document}
```

(I see no displacement, but you can always add a \leavevmode before the target to make sure that you are in horizontal mode.)

Comment: Using of `\leavevmode` can solve the problem of unexpected displacement of `\lfoot`. But when the page zoom is large enough, clicking the "Author name" will jump to the next line of `\lfoot` which make the content of `\lfoot` unviewed. Would you help me with this?